# PHP Regex for specific quotation

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some extreme trouble understanding how I can only get the characters inside the double quote when I only want it to get the characters when it's something like:

```
Item.name = "thisCouldBeAnything"
```

When there could be other double quotes in the parser. I'm having extreme difficulty to understand what the regex would be.

Comment: You mean it could be `"this"Could"BeAnything"` or you mean double quotes somewhere else?  You need more detail in your question, like inputs that should/shouldn't match etc.

Comment: My bad, I need it to exactly be Item.name = "" It can't just search for double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment *I need it to exactly be `Item.name = ""` It can't just search for double quotes*.  Assuming you want to capture what's in double quotes:

```
preg_match_all('/Item.name = "(.*)"/', $string, $matches);
```

Or if the value inside the double quotes should not contain double quotes:

```
preg_match_all('/Item.name = "([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);
```

Or to capture it all:

```
preg_match_all('/(Item.name = ".*")/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need just a valid string literal, i.e. text enclosed in double quotes and this text could possibly include backslash-escaped double quotes, try this expression:

```
"((?:\\"|[^"])*?)"
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YoiDtP/1

Answer (score 1):

Or (highjacking [**@Dmitry's example**](https://regex101.com/r/YoiDtP/2)):

```
([\"\'])(.*?(?<!\\))\1
```

---

This says:

```
([\"\'])    # capture ' or " into group 1
(           # second group
    .*?     # anything lazily
    (?<!\\) # neg. lookbehind, make sure there's no backslash
)
\1          # the formerly captured string literal of group 1
```

*Note, that you don't need to escape string literals in square brackets (`[...]`) but the StackOverflow renderer makes it very ugly otherwise.*

---

Full `PHP` snippet (note the [unnecessary] group called "value" and the double escaped backslash):

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
Item.name = "thisCouldBeAnything"
Item.name = "thisCouldBe\"Any\"thing"
Item.name = 'thisCouldBeAnything'
Item.name = 'thisCouldBe\'Any\'"thing'
DATA;

$regex = '~(["\'])(?P<value>.*?(?<!\\\\))\1~';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
   echo $match["value"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey this works except the following data also comes in as Item.value Item.ID etc, my bad for not mentioning on the original post ;/ However I do not want something like Item.Desc etc